# Problems parsing an XML files using python using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a bunch of videos and XML files which contain data about objects in the files. I am trying to write some function which compares each frame of each video against that videos XML file but when I loop through a sub-sub element of the root and print its attributes not all the objects are being found. An example XML file is linked [here](https://pastebin.com/HarkUz0X)

I wrote these two functions

```
def setUP():
    os.chdir('/home/abdi/Desktop/TestOpt/FishCLEF2015- TestDataset/Combined/')
    listOfGT=[]



 for file in glob.glob("*.flv"):
        number,types=file.split(".")
        listOfGT.append(number)
    #print(len(listOfGT))
    total=0
    for names in listOfGT:
        total+=1
        print ("**** New File is {} ****".format(str(names) +".xml"))

        tree = ET.parse(str(names) + ".xml")  
        root = tree.getroot()
        NumberOfframes=LastFrames(root)
        for frames in root:
            print("For Frame: {}".format(frames.attrib["id"]))
            jakoObject(frames,NumberOfframes,names)
```

This sets up everything by looping through all the files finding the root structure and looping through each sublist which corresponds to 1 frame in the image

```
def jakoObject(frames,NumberOfframes,names):
cam = cv.VideoCapture(str(names) + ".flv")
frame_count=0
while frame_count != NumberOfframes:
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    attrib=frames.attrib["id"]

    if (frame_count==NumberOfframes):
        print("Yatta")
        break
    else:
        frame_count+=1

    if (frame_count==int(attrib)):
        for objects in frames:
            # print("For Frame: {} and object {}".format(frames.attrib["id"],franmes.objects.attrib["id"]))
            print(objects.attrib)
```

I then use this function to play through the video, if the current frame number is equal the the current frame number found through the root structure then a loop through each sublist named objects is started.

I have called printed the attributed of the file. However, what happens is that for a lot of the "object" sublists no attributes are found. But the attributes are found for another frame inside the same XML file.

For the file linked above, the output is

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Check what happens by adding the line

```
print(frame_count, attrib, NumberOfframes)
```

in `jakoObject` after

```
attrib=frames.attrib["id"]
```

Then you should see why it is being skipped.